# Intercept .asmx request with an attribute on POST requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

Is there a way to intercept a HttpPost request to a `.asmx` WebService using an Attribute?

I already have a `SoapExtension` that validates what I need for SOAP requests, but I need to do the same validation in `POST` requests.

Comment: I don't know about attributes but it is pretty easy to implement an IHttpHandler to intercept requests.

Comment: Got it, but is there a way to "apply" the IHttpHandler only to certain methods instead of the entire WebService?

Comment: If there is, I am not aware. What I do is inspect the request to see if it is one I need to handle. You can also use HttpModules, [it depends on exactly what you want to do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)